# Orthogonal tangent vectors on Sphere in arbitary dimension

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Consider $\mathbb R^{4}$ with coordinates $x^{1},...,x^{4}$. We can write down the following forms:
$$x^{1}dx^{2}-x^{2}dx^{1}+x^{3}dx^{4}-x^{4}dx^{3}$$
$$x^{1}dx^{3}-x^{3}dx^{1}-x^{2}dx^{4}+x^{4}dx^{2}$$
$$x^{1}dx^{4}-x^{4}dx^{1}+x^{2}dx^{3}-x^{3}dx^{2}$$
these are pairwise orthogonal and they are also orthogonal to radial form:
$$x^{1}dx^{1}+x^{2}dx^{2}+x^{3}dx^{3}+x^{4}dx^{4}$$
Can we write down such a forms in higher dimension explicitly? More precisly, we are looking for $\alpha_{k}=a_{ij}x^{i}dx^{j}$ $1\le k\le n-1$ and $\alpha_{i}$'s are pairwise orthogonal and they are also orthogonal to :
$$x^{1}dx^{1}+...+x^{n}dx^{n}$$

Comment: The maximum number of mutually orthogonal forms (vanishing only at the origin, and assuming homogeneity) one can build orthogonal to the radial form on $\Bbb R^n$ is $\rho(n) - 1$, where $\rho(n)$ is the $n$th *Radon-Hurwitz number*. In particular, for $n$ odd, the Hairy Ball Theorem implies that there are no such forms. The sequence $\rho(n) - 1$ is the content of http://oeis.org/A053381.

Answer (score 2):

If by orthogonal you require them to be nonzero, then that **cannot** be done in general.

If you have a one form $\alpha$ which is orthogonal to $x^{1}dx^{1}+...+x^{n}dx^{n}$, then this $\alpha$ can be thought of a nonzero one form on $S^{n-1}$. This forces that the Euler characteristic to be zero. In this case which means $n$ has to be even. (So you cannot find one on (e.g.) $\mathbb R^5$).

What's more, you want $n-1$ pairwise orthogonal one (not only one), which is the same as requiring that the tangent bundle of $S^{n-1}$ be trivial.

That is true only if $n=2, 4, 8$.

Comment: Of course, OP's forms are not nonvanishing either, they all vanish at $0$. Probably one should allow this and demand homogeneity of the forms under dilation (this makes more precise too the statement that "$\alpha$ can be thought of [as] a nonzero one form on $S^{n -1}$), as this reduces the problem to the one on the sphere implicit in this answer.